# Spring Rest Template body is null responseEntity.getBody()

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring and I am using version 4.3.0. In my code I am getting the body as null always when I call the method within another rest call. However when I test this method using postman it works perfectly fine. I am not sure what I am missing here. I looked into other similar questions and tried the HttpEntity options but still I am missing something here.

Here is my code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/location/{uuid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ArrayList<String> getLocation(@PathVariable("uuid") String uuid) {

    String uriString = "http://user1:pass1@10.10.10.10/LocationProvider/api/" + uuid;

    try {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
        HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uriString, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
        String locations = responseEntity.getBody();

        // THIS IS THE RESPONSE I GET IN POSTMAN BUT IN DEBUGGER ITS NULL
//          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
//          <Locations>
//              <City name="New" street="First_Ave" state=""/>
//              <City name="old" street="Second_Ave" state=""/>
//          </Locations>
        return locations;

    } catch (RestClientException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return null;
    } 
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Provide your POSTman request dump please. You can to that by clicking on "code" link on right corner of postman and export it in HTTP format

Comment: are you getting null value as response ?

Comment: try adding this restTemplate.getMessageConverters()
        .add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")));

Comment: @TechBreak 


GET /LocationProvider/api/_mFcBIaoWEeaIlf6rwD6KgA HTTP/1.1
Host: user1:pass1@10.10.10.10
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 33c5d919-f4b9-ecd9-1f5b-c9071fc5d298

Answer (score 1):

Looks like everything was just fine from the code point of view. When I was calling the code in postman there was no "/n" at the end of the uriString.

Whereas when the method was being called by other method it was uuid with "/n".

I have just added .trim() to my uri as below and it worked.

```
String uriString = "http://user1:pass1@10.10.10.10/LocationProvider/api/" + uuid.trim();
```

I guess it's a good idea to pay attention to every charterer